# connecting a database to create hibernate reverse engineering file

Tags: mysql, hibernate

i have created two databases for the same connection string. When trying to create the .reveng file using netbeans it shows me the list of tables in one table only. And i couldn't find any option to select the database either. Is there a way to access the other databases in the same db connection?

Comment: 2 DB's and same Connection string?

Comment: yes both dbs are in the same connection